# how to make JTextPane paint anti-aliased font?

Tags: java, swing, antialiasing

in the a swing app i'm rendering text with a custom `JComponent`, using `Graphics.drawString()`. here is a sample:
[aa text http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/4928/drawstringsample.jpg](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/4928/drawstringsample.jpg)
in that same app, i'm rendering text using a `JTextPane`. here is a sample:
[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/1134/jtextpanesample.jpg](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/1134/jtextpanesample.jpg)

can you notice how the lower sample is a little 'smudged'? well, i can't figure out how to make it look like the upper sample.

thanks, asaf :-)

---

update:

- `System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","false")` and `"lcd"` too aren't working.
- `((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF)` in `paint()` isn't working
- `putClientProperty(`**`sun.swing.SwingUtilities2`**`.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, Boolean.TRUE)` gives `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to sun.swing.SwingUtilities2$AATextInfo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`putClientProperty(SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, null);`

Comment: If this is the actual solution, please mark it as such (by toggling the "accepted answer" checkbox), TIA!

Comment: It's not working with java 9 : java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY.

Answer (score 6):

This will result in an antialiased font in a JLabel. Make sure you call super.paintComponent(g); after setting the RenderingHints.

```
JLabel lblFont = new JLabel(){

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                graphics2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
```

Comment: you're answering 'cause you've tried it and that solved your problem?

Comment: yes, in my case i could switch anti-aliasing on and off with this approach.

Comment: @b1tk0pf Combining your aproach together with the following code makes for even smoother text - `jTextPane1.putClientProperty(SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, null);`

Comment: I'd prefer this solution as it antialiases text when drawing on any graphics (in my case BufferedImage), but the "putClientProperty" would be better for Swing applications. (Probably, I still hate the idea of using sun.* packages)

Comment: It's not working on JTextPane whereas SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your result to look like the the upper sample, then you want to *disable* anti-aliasing.

The first sample in your question has anti-aliasing disabled and the second sample has it enabled.

According to http://mindprod.com/jgloss/antialiasing.html the following code should help:

```
jtextArea.putClientProperty(com.sun.java.swing.SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Notice that the reference to `com.sun.java.*` will make your application non-portable to non-Sun JVMs (and possibly to different versions of Sun JVMs).

Comment: tried System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","false") and "lcd" too, but w/o results.

Comment: tried ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF) in paint(), but w/o results.

Comment: and putClientProperty(sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, Boolean.TRUE) gives java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to sun.swing.SwingUtilities2$AATextInfo