# Java: How to enable text anti-aliasing in a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, antialiasing

This is what I have so far, but the text in the field isn't anti-aliased. I've tried googling it for a while but couldn't find any threads discussing it (much to my surprise). Does anyone know how to do this?

```
public class SearchField extends JTextField{
    public SearchField(){
       super();
       this.setOpaque(false);
       this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fieldWidth, fieldHeight));
       this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,8,4,8));
       this.setFont(fieldFont);
     }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics paramGraphics){
          Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) paramGraphics;
          g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                             RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

          g.setColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY);
          g.fillRoundRect(0,0,fieldWidth,fieldHeight,4,4);
          super.paintComponent(g);
     }
  }
```

Comment: This question on StackOverflow maybe of help: [how to make JTextPane paint anti-aliased font?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2266199/851432)

Comment: `g.fillRoundRect(0,0,fieldWidth,fieldHeight,4,4);`  This sounds like the job for a [custom border](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556) on a standard `JTextField`.

Comment: If one simple line of code does the trick and it's easily efficient enough, why bother with a custom border? But a good point, I must admit.

Comment: _why bother_ because in the long run you'll be most productive if you follow the winds of any framework you're using (instead of fighting it in detours). The wind of borders is ... using borders

Comment: Why not use the tools at our disposal to build the components we require? A border is also just another class, so in this case the efficiency / consequences of a `RoundRectangle` does the job very nicely. Not arguing though - there are many ways that you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've decided to do until I can find a more elegant solution - works well.

```
private class SearchField extends JTextField{

   private final int fieldWidth = 375;
   private final int fieldHeight = 30;
   private final Font fieldFont = FontLoader.getCustomFont("Gotham-Bold.ttf", 15);
   private final Color foreground = ColorConstants.SEARCH_FIELD_FOREGROUND;
   private final Color background = ColorConstants.SEARCH_FIELD_BACKGROUND;

   public SearchField(){
      super();
      this.setOpaque(false);
      this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fieldWidth, fieldHeight));
      this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
      this.setFont(fieldFont);
      this.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
      this.setSelectedTextColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics paramGraphics){
      Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) paramGraphics.create();
      GraphicUtils.enableAntiAliasing(g); //RenderingHints
      g.setColor(background);
      g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight, 4, 4);
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(foreground);
      g.drawString(this.getText(), 5, 20);
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure where GraphicUtils is from, but for that line the following can be done `g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);`

Comment: It's a class I wrote to apply various `RenderingHints`, but thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found it helpful to use [`TextLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513), as one can condition the [`FontRenderContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html) with both `isAntiAliased` and `usesFractionalMetrics`.

The example's use of `BufferedImage` is coincidental.