# Text antialiasing broken in Java 1.7 (Windows)

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, antialiasing

Antialiasing rendering hints for text seem broken for Swing components Java 1.7 (Windows). Setting  `KEY_ANTIALIASING` and/or `KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING` does not affect anymore the display of `JLabel`, `JEditorPane`, etc. - but actually I need different settings in my project.

You can compare the different behavior in `Java 1.6` (jdk1.6.0_45) and `Java 1.7` (jdk1.7.0_40) in this screenshot, produced with the test program below:

[image: Left side run with Java 1.6, right side with Java 1.7]

Left side is Java 1.6, right side is Java 1.7. The first column is painted with `Graphics2D.drawString`, the second with a `JLabel`. In Java 1.6 the rendering hints affect the JLabel display, whereas in Java 1.7 all JLabels render the same (except for the one with fractional metrics).

Do you know how I can have the antialiasing hints affect Swing components in Java 1.7?

Test program:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class AntialiasMain extends JFrame {
    public AntialiasMain() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("default", null));

        HashMap<Key, Object> hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("AA off", hints));

        hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("AA on", hints));

        hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("TextAA off", hints));

        hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("TextAA on", hints));

        hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("AA+TextAA on", hints));

        hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("AA+FracMetr on", hints));

        hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("AA+TextLCD on", hints));

        hints = new HashMap<Key, Object>();
        hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
        panel.add(new AntialiasLabel("TextLCD on", hints));

        getContentPane().add(panel);

    }

    class AntialiasLabel extends JLabel {
        private final HashMap<Key, Object>  hints;
        private final String                label;

        private static final String         PALYNDROME          = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

        public AntialiasLabel(String label, HashMap<Key, Object> hints) {
            super(PALYNDROME);
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 150, 10, 10));
            this.label = label;
            this.hints = hints;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            if (hints != null)
                g2.setRenderingHints(hints);
            g2.drawString("Setting: " + label, 2, getHeight() / 2 + 5);
            super.paintComponent(g2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new AntialiasMain();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:  System properties `swing.aatext` and `awt.useSystemAAFontSettings` have no effect. Neither has changing the `Look and Feel`.

Comment: Could you try the same code with another L&F?

Comment: Good idea. Same results with Nimbus, Metal, Windows, and Substance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266567/3080094). Update the code in your question with:

```
private static final Object AA_TEXT_PROP = getAaTextProperty();

public static Object getAaTextProperty() {

    Object aatext = null;
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("sun.swing.SwingUtilities2");
        Field f = c.getField("AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY");
        aatext = f.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aatext;
}
...

public AntialiasLabel(String label, HashMap<Key, Object> hints) {
    super(PALYNDROME);
    putClientProperty(AA_TEXT_PROP, null);
    ...
}
```

Tested on Java 1.7 Windows. Note that recent (Feb-2015) Windows updates like [kb3013455](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_update/kb3013455-ms15-010-causes-font-corruption/8640d38d-19bd-46b6-9af0-6213c05107d3) have broken font anti-aliasing on many systems.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. After 1.5 years.. congrats!

Comment: Or simply : putClientProperty(SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, null); Also it's no more working with Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

First, a few points on the behavior of Swing components:

- The UI delegate for a Swing component, which you are calling when you call `super.paintComponent()` can set up whatever rendering hints it wants - it appear that the UI delegate for JLabel from the look and feel is overriding yours
- If you want *not* to use antialiasing (i.e., you're using remote X or similar), you should probably use `MetalLookAndFeel` which was designed with that use-case in mind.
- There is no guarantee that the UI delegate for any component will not override whatever you set for rendering hints - i.e. the behavior you're seeing is perfectly legal

That being said, as of JDK 1.6 (and therefore as far as I know, 1.7, but no promises) you could access the default rendering hints used by AWT and Swing via an **undocumented** (and therefore not supported) desktop property

`(Map<RenderingHints.Key, Object>)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints"));`

Here is a [usage example I wrote for NetBeans, circa 2004 - see the `getHints()` method](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/b6b62b125b68/o.n.swing.tabcontrol/src/org/netbeans/swing/tabcontrol/plaf/ColorUtil.java).  It does the opposite of what you are after, since it is trying to force antialiasing to be on.  But manipulating the contents of that `Map`, or replacing it, may work to globally change the antialiasing settings.

Comment: Thanks. That was already suggested by StanislavL, see comments above. Changing the L&F does *not* help (try yourself by running the  example code above; once with 1.7, then compare with 1.7).

Comment: I get the map, but it already contains the proper hint; the Motif LAF just ignores it ☹

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question, but I ran into the same problems.

After investigating, I found that if you add the following to the main() method the code works as expected:

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","off");
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "false");
```

It seems the defaults for Java 7 changed from both properties 'off' to both 'on'